# Delete file not affecting StreamWriter in Linux

Tags: linux, .net-core

In Windows a file is locked while it is open in a `StreamWriter` (and in general), but in Linux you can delete/unlink a file while it is in use.

I have a .Net Core systemd service that is writing to a file using a `StreamWriter`. And if the file is removed the service keeps writing to the `StreamWriter` without any exceptions thrown. I assume this is expected behavior.

So how do I detect a file is deleted when writing to it in Linux and .Net Core? Do I have to call File.Exists before every call to `StreamWriter.WriteLine`? Is there some way to tell `StreamWriter` to reopen/recreate the file at the next write call?

Answer (score 0):

In general Linux applications don't try to check if their open files have been deleted or renamed. It'd be a lot of work and is not their responsibility.

Instead, the process that's messing with the file with either restart the application or signal it. Many applications install a signal handler for `SIGHUP` and use it as a signal to reload configuration files and re-open log files. Less sophisticated applications can simply be killed and restarted, though that introduces a short downtime window. [Log rotation](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+log+rotation) programs can commonly be configured to use either strategy on a per-app basis.